# I'm facing a problem with my web scraping code I don't really know the problem is

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining, data-extraction

I'm facing a problem with my web scraping code I don't really know what the problem is!
could any one of you guys help me, please
this code is used to scrape data from a job's website
I used python and some libraries such as beatifulsoup

```py
job_titles = []
company_names = []
locations = []
links = []
salaries = []
#using requests to fetch the URL :
result = requests.get('https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=python&a=hpb')

#saving page's content/markup :
src = result.content

#create soup object to parse content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(src ,'lxml')
#print(soup)

#Now we're looking for the elements that conains the info we need (job title, job skills, company name, location)
job_title = soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"css-m604qf"})
company_name = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "css-17s97q8"})
location = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "css-5wys0k"})

#Making a loop over returned lists to extract needed info into other lists 
for I in range(len(job_title)):
    job_titles.append(job_title[I].text)
    links.append(job_title[I].find("a").attrs['href'])
    company_names.append(company_name[I].text)
    locations.append(location[I].text)
for link in links :
    results = requests.get(link)
    src = results.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    salary = soup.find("a", {"class": "css-4xky9y"})
    salaries.append(salary.text)
#Creating a CSV file to store our values 
file_list = [job_titles, company_names, locations, links, salaries]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)
with open("C:\\Users\\NOUFEL\\Desktop\\scraping\\wazzuf\\jobs.csv", "w") as myfile :
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(["job title", "company name", "location", "links", "salaries"])
    wr.writerows(exported)
```

the problem is
PS C:\Users\NOUFEL> & C:/Users/NOUFEL/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/NOUFEL/Desktop/ScrapeWuzzuf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\NOUFEL\Desktop\ScrapeWuzzuf.py", line 33, in 
results = requests.get(link)
File "C:\Users\NOUFEL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\NOUFEL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\NOUFEL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 515, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\NOUFEL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "C:\Users\NOUFEL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 318, in prepare
self.prepare_url(url, params)
File "C:\Users\NOUFEL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 392, in prepare_url
raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/jobs/p/1XOMELtShdah-Flask-Python-Backend-Developer-Virtual-Worker-Now-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///jobs/p/1XOMELtShdah-Flask-Python-Backend-Developer-Virtual-Worker-Now-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Neufel, would be possible to you to edit the post and include the web scrapping code that you are using? And also what is the error message that you receive when running the code?

Comment: if you would read error message (or you would display `link`) then you would see that you get `relative link` like `/jobs/p/1XOMELtShdah-Flask-Python-...` and you have to add `https://wuzzuf.net/` at the beginning to get `absolute link`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would read error message

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/jobs/p/1XOMELtShdah-Flask-Python-Backend-
```

or if you would display `link` then you would see that you get `relative link` like `/jobs/p/1XOMELtShdah-Flask-Python-...` and you have to add `https://wuzzuf.net` at the beginning to get `absolute link`.

```
results = requests.get(  "https://wuzzuf.net" + link )
```

Comment: I did what you asked I'm sorry I'm new here I never posted at stack overflow thank you for responding .

Comment: @diogo wernik  
I did what you asked I'm sorry I'm new here I never posted at stack overflow thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

To get the required data, you need to get a "container" selector that contains all the information about the job we need as child elements. In our case, this is the `.css-1gatmva` selector. Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to easily pick selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser (*not always works perfectly*).

Problems with site parsing may arise because when you try to request a site, it may consider that this is a bot, so that this does not happen, you need to send `headers` that contain [`user-agent` in the request](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#user-agent), then the site will assume that you're a user and display information.

The request might be blocked (if using `requests` as default `user-agent` in `requests` library is a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). Additional step could be to [`rotate user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on.

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/problem-with-web-scraping-code-beautifulsoup#main.py).

```py
import requests, lxml, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "python"   # query
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
# https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36"
}

html = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

data = []

for result in soup.select(".css-1gatmva"):                            
    title = result.select_one(".css-m604qf .css-o171kl").text         
    company_name = result.select_one(".css-17s97q8").text             
    adding_time = result.select_one(".css-4c4ojb, .css-do6t5g").text  
    location = result.select_one(".css-5wys0k").text                  
    employment = result.select_one(".css-1lh32fc").text               
    snippet = result.select_one(".css-1lh32fc+ div").text             

    data.append({
      "title" : title,
      "company_name" : company_name,
      "adding_time" : adding_time,
      "location" : location,
      "employment" : employment,
      "snippet" : snippet    
    })
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Example output

```json
[
    {
    "title": "Python Developer For Job portal",
    "company_name": "Fekra Technology Solutions and Construction -",
    "adding_time": "24 days ago",
    "location": "Dokki, Giza, Egypt ",
    "employment": "Full TimeWork From Home",
    "snippet": "Experienced \u00b7 4+ Yrs of Exp \u00b7 IT/Software Development \u00b7 Engineering - Telecom/Technology \u00b7 backend \u00b7 Computer Science \u00b7 Django \u00b7 Flask \u00b7 Git \u00b7 Information Technology (IT) \u00b7 postgres \u00b7 Python"
  },
  {
    "title": "Senior Python Linux Engineer",
    "company_name": "El-Sewedy Electrometer -",
    "adding_time": "1 month ago",
    "location": "6th of October, Giza, Egypt ",
    "employment": "Full Time",
    "snippet": "Experienced \u00b7 3 - 5 Yrs of Exp \u00b7 IT/Software Development \u00b7 Engineering - Telecom/Technology \u00b7 Software Development \u00b7 Python \u00b7 C++ \u00b7 Information Technology (IT) \u00b7 Computer Science \u00b7 SQL \u00b7 Programming \u00b7 Electronics"
  }
]
[
  {
    "title": "Senior Python Developer",
    "company_name": "Trufla -",
    "adding_time": "2 days ago",
    "location": "Heliopolis, Cairo, Egypt ",
    "employment": "Full Time",
    "snippet": "Experienced \u00b7 4+ Yrs of Exp \u00b7 IT/Software Development \u00b7 Engineering - Telecom/Technology \u00b7 Agile \u00b7 APIs \u00b7 AWS \u00b7 Computer Science \u00b7 Git \u00b7 Linux \u00b7 Python \u00b7 REST"
  },
      # ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to use = results = requests.get(  "https://wuzzuf.net" + link )

```
for link in links :
    results = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net"+link)
    src = results.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    salary = soup.find("a", {"class": "css-4xky9y"})
    salaries.append(salary.text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).